# Mongoose: Find all rows without specyfic many data ( $ne )

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have a small problem in mongoose where I want to select all rows except the specified ids.

My code for example:

```
 var ids = [{id: 123},{id: 222},{id:333}];
 User.find({_id: {$ne: ids.id }},'firstName lastName _id avatar',function (err,users) {...});
```

**Exact Problem:**
I have a variable with many user ids, and I want to select only users without these ids.

Comment: If your array had exact keys that match the collection `_id` field then you would simply query using [**`$nor`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/nor/) as `var ids = [{ "_id": 123 } , { "_id": 222 } , { "_id": 333 }]; User.find({ "$nor": ids }, 'firstName lastName _id avatar', function (err, users) { ... });`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We gonna use the [$nin](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/nin/) from mongodb, that exclude given array from the result.

We perform a map in order to have a plain array of id like `[123, 222, 333]`

```
  const ids = [
    {
      id: 123,
    }, {
      id: 222,
    }, {
      id: 333,
  }];

  User.find(
   // Query
   {
     _id: {
        $nin: ids.map(x => x.id), 
     },
   },

   // Projection
   'firstName lastName _id avatar',

   // Callback
   function (err,users) {...});
```